# Simple R Language summary function is giving "Object Not Found" error

Tags: r

I'm trying to read a stata file in R Studio using the following code:

```
    library(foreign)        
    cdata = read.dta("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/crime.dta")

    summary(cdata)
```

However, the console is displaying the following error:

> summary(cdata)
>   Error in summary(cdata) : object 'cdata' not found

Can anyone please help me out that why is this happening even though I'm just copying and pasting simple example from this link:
http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/rreg.htm

Here's my sessioninfo():

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] magrittr_1.5    htmltools_0.3.5 tools_3.3.1     Rcpp_0.12.7     stringi_1.1.1  
 [6] rmarkdown_1.0   knitr_1.14      stringr_1.1.0   digest_0.6.10   evaluate_0.9
```

Comment: This is one of the most comment error messages in R. In your case, the `read.dta()` function must not have executed successfully. Make sure you first run `library(foreign)`

Comment: @DMC if the OP didnt load the library it would produce the following error ``Error: could not find function "read.dta"`` before producing the error described in the question above

Comment: Just did that but still the same error. Now my code looks like this:

    library(foreign)
    cdata = read.dta("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/crime.dta")
    summary(cdata)

Comment: post your ``sessionInfo()`` please, also what happens when you run ``str(cdata)`` and/or ``ls(cdata)``?

Comment: I have posted my sessioninfo() in the original post.

Comment: str(cdata) gives the same error of object 'cdata' not found.

Comment: Based on your `sessionInfo`, it doesn't look like you loaded package foreign.  If you had you would see a line in the session info that said `other attached packages:` with `foreign` listed beneath.  I'm surprised you didn't get other error messages running the first two lines of your code.  Make sure you have installed foreign, then run the first two lines of code again.

Comment: @aosmith is there any different way to load this package because I'm adding [library(foreign)]. But still the same issue:

Here is my updated code:

install.packages("foreign")
library(foreign)
cdata = read.dta("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/crime.dta")
summary(cdata)

Comment: Do you get any other error messages with installing the package, loading the package, or using `read.dta`?  As `foreign` isn't attached in your session, you should get an error message of `could not find function "read.dta"`.

Comment: Nope. Nothing. Only that function not found error.

Comment: function not found error? thats what @aosmith is asking, or do you mean object not found error? I find it hard to believe that ``cdata = read.dta("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/crime.dta")`` doesn't produce an error...

Comment: Here's the message I receive when I try to run read.dta:

> cdata = read.dta("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/crime.dta")
Error: could not find function "read.dta"

Comment: The issue is resolved but I have no idea. I re-installed the Foreign library (as it was already installed), restarted R Studio, deleted the older "Foreign" package (even though both new and old were same versions) and then executed the code and then it worked.

May be restarting R Studio did the trick.